# django manytomany postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new to django and postgresql. Basically I want to display the players in a team.

my database looks like this

player table:

[image]

team table:

[image]

and a playteam table that links IDs together using foreign key:

[image]

I use inspectdb > models.py to create models in django and registered them in admin.py.

Inside the django admin site, it looks like this:

[image]
When I click into teams, the two teams are shown and when i click into one of the team, only the name and id of the team are shown.

[image]
what I want is that there is a player field inside each team where all the players in this team can be shown. But I dont know how:(

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign your tables like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,...)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,...)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
```

No need for extra table Play Team